# What does "SetEnv PHPRC" do and how is it used?

Tags: htaccess, php

I have a client with some technical skills who likes to take a look at files and understand how they work.

Yesterday, we installed Ninja Firewall in their WordPress and their web host server setup needs `SetEnv PHPRC` to the php.ini path in the .htaccess file. I would like an explanation of `SetEnv PHPRC` in Plain English for my client, but my research has only come up with a little bit of this and a little bit of that and no clear explanations.

Comment: Try googling environment variables instead of "SetEnv"?

Comment: It's the same problem with searching for environmental variables. PHPRC is a replacement for php.ini, I don't seem to find information on why and what the difference is. The sites seem to tell how to create one. We don't need to create it, I just to explain it better.

Comment: I have removed your request for an external resource.   It would be preferable that the explanation that you are looking for gets written as an answer here.

Comment: http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/linux-manual/env-howto.html is an external resource. I hate duplicating content, so I'm doing this as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PHPRC is a replacement for php.ini, ... The sites seem to tell how to create one.

I think that is something a bit different (regarding creating a "phprc" file - a local PHP config file - something unique to DreamHost AFAIK)?

The `PHPRC` (PHP Runtime Configuration) *environment variable* is one way to tell PHP where to find the main `php.ini` file. It can sometimes be used to *change* the location of the main `php.ini` file.
Reference: http://php.net/configuration.file

On some hosts, the `PHPRC` environment variable can also be used to set a local (per site) `php.ini` PHP config file. (Otherwise, trying to change the location of `php.ini` on a *shared host* will not do anything, apart from setting the environment variable.) This can also be achieved using a local `.user.ini` file and/or `.htaccess` - but this can vary from host to host.

The Apache directive `SetEnv` (part of `mod_env`) simply sets this environment variable. `PHPRC` is then available to any scripting language that reads these environment variables.

#### Why is this required for NinjaFirewall?

The [NinjaFirewall docs](https://nintechnet.com/ninjafirewall/wp-edition/help/) state:

> **Installation...** NinjaFirewall will need to add some instructions to your system files (php.ini, .htaccess). In most cases, it will be able to detect your configuration and to make those changes for you

My guess is that NinjaFirewall needs a local (`php.ini` in your case) config file in which to make changes. Or, less likely, needs the `PHPRC` env var set in order to be able find the location of the `php.ini` file, which can then be edited. (The specific path that is being set will tell you this... is it a path within your webspace? Or somewhere else on the file system?)

It's also [stated in this WordPress.org thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ninjafirewall-installation-failed/), that:

> The `SetEnv PHPRC` directive in the .htaccess is only needed when you are using a php.ini that is not recursive, i.e., that does not apply to subdirectories.

Although that doesn't seem make much sense to me? (If `php.ini` is not "recursive", then I don't think you would be using `php.ini` to begin with?)

Further reading:

- [Troubleshoot NinjaFirewall installation problems](http://blog.nintechnet.com/troubleshoot-ninjafirewall-installation-problems/) - discusses `php.ini` and other config files.

Comment: I think that your answer explains a piece of information I was missing. Based on your comments, I understand thatPHPRC does not replace php.ini, it points to where the php.ini file is stored. If I am indeed understanding your explanation correctly, my simplified version is an answer my client will understand.

Comment: Yes, it points to where `php.ini` is stored. A custom PHP config file just for this site _I assume_. I'm curious... what path is set for PHPRC? Is it pointing to somewhere within the webspace itself? Or somewhere else on the file system?

Comment: It is pointed to a php.ini file within the website files. That is, it's inside of the http accessible file structure.